# Move to next column when adding data to table

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to add a section of data from Excel to a table in Access. I used the TransferSpreadSheet method the the data comes out of order in the table.

The next thing I tried was to try to add every cell column by column to the table, but that does not work because to keep adding the data to the next row instead of going to the next column, and then adding to the first row of the next column.

In general I have 7 rows/cells and 100 columns in Excel. I want it to look the same in the table as it does in the spreadsheet

Here is what I have tried:

```
For i = 0 To 7
    For j = 5 To 100
        xColumn = MultiLetter(j)
        xCell = shNames + "!" + xColumn + CStr(BCellNum + i) + ":" + xColumn + CStr(BCellNum + i)
        'xCell = shNames + "!E" + CStr(BCellNum + i) + ":" + xColumn + CStr(BCellNum + i)

        DoEvents
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "Sheet1", _
                ExcelFileList(XFile), No, xCell, yes
    Next j
Next i
```

What it ends up being

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

What I want it to be

```
A     E
B     F
C     G
D     H
```

Can anyone help my dilemma?

Comment: is the table structure already defined in access? and does it mirror the column list in Excel - at least in terms of headers, even if it not in exact order?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes the table structure is already defined. It mirrors the column list in excel, but the section of data i am trying to get is in the middle of the spreadsheet, so there are not really any headers, just the standard column letters in the spreadsheet

Comment: You can use ADO rather than transferspreadsheet, but you should not care about column order, tables are not for users, so a form will solve the problem.

Comment: you can get rid of the rows that will not be imported, or just move the rows that will be imported to a new worksheet in a new workbook then and place the column headers in row 1 then use transferspreadhsheet against that workbook ... basically manipulate the data in Excel to be in the format you want, then import it ...

Answer (score 0):

Why not extract the data to a new worksheet first and then use the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet on the new sheet!